# PHP directories including database file

Tags: php, directory

I have a member_config file that has all of my functions in it.

At the top of this page, i call `include_once('configuration/db.php');`.

I include my header.php file in my main.php file to load the navigation and such.

In my header file, I require a function from my member_config.php file.

At the top of my header.php, I need to include my memebr_config.php file so it can read my functions.

When I try to add `require_once('../configuration/member_configuration/member_config.php');` at the top of my header, it's not getting the database file. An error shows :  ***include_once(configuration/db.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in configuration\member_configuration\member_config.php on line 2***

Because my member_config file is in a different directory, it doesn't allow me to call the member_config file due to the db.php not allowing the correct file location in the member_config from the header.php

Anyone know how to overcome this issue ?

***FILE PATHS:***

member_config.php = `configuration/member_configuration/member_config.php`

header.php = `includes/header.php`

db.php = `configuration/db.php`

Comment: Can you add the file paths to the files? it's not clear this way

Comment: Please add a directory structure for all files.

Comment: try removing `../` at the beginning of your path `('../configuration/member_configuration/member_config.php')`

Comment: @ScorpionCode and then it says : `require_once(configuration/member_configuration/member_config.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in includes\header.php on line 3`

Comment: are you using the function `require_once` in db.php or header.php?

Comment: @ScorpionCode Why would I require files in the db.php ? I need files to go to db.php not get anything from it. So the header.php

Comment: wait I get it. You need to change `include_once('configuration/db.php')` to  `include_once('../../db.php')` EDIT: my mistake `include_once('../db.php')` I believe you only need to do `../` once

Comment: because it's looking for the db.php file in the member_config. so you need to go back to the configuration folder, in order to find it

Comment: @ScorpionCode No buddy. I've tried that. I have more than just this file in this directory going to the db.php file. I have files also from site_config.php and some other files. I should not be changing this. I have 1 work around but it makes my code look scruffy. I could re-define the functions in the member_config.php to the header.php and just include the raw db.php include and change the name of each function. But like I said, this makes my code look very scruffy and pointless.

Comment: Why don't you just include/require everything in one file? That's what I always do. In Index.php I include 4/5 different files. The only thing that matters is the order

Comment: @ScorpionCode Okay how would I go about doing this ?

Comment: you can try what simurgrai said. Or you do this: in main.php, `include_once('path/to/db.php');`
`include_once('path/to/member_config.php');`
`include_once('path/to/header.php');`

Comment: @ScorpionCode I already do this.

Comment: you said you `include` `db.php` in `member_config` and `header` in `main`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Document Tree is

```
.
├── configuration
│   ├── db.php
│   └── member_configuration
│       └── member_config.php
├── includes
│   └── header.php
└── main.php
```

includes/header.php

```
<?php
include_once "configuration/member_configuration/member_config.php";
echo "<pre>";
echo "header.php".PHP_EOL;
?>
```

main.php

```
<?php
include_once "includes/header.php";
echo "main.php".PHP_EOL;
?>
```

configuration/db.php

```
<?php
echo "<pre>";
echo "db.php".PHP_EOL;
?>
```

configuration/member_configuration/member_config.php

```
<?php
include_once "configuration/db.php";
echo "mc donfig functions here".PHP_EOL;
?>
```

Calling main.php in the browser will output

```
db.php
mc donfig functions here
header.php
main.php
```